# How to import Google Cloud Client Library in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, google-cloud-platform

How would one import the Google Cloud Client Library found at :
http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.8.0/index.html

Into eclipse, non maven, java?

I have found no .jar file in the library.

EDIT:

I tried adding the .jar file but I still get "the import could not be resolved" on the following imports:

```
import com.google.gcloud.AuthCredentials;
import com.google.gcloud.datastore.Datastore;
import com.google.gcloud.datastore.DatastoreOptions;
import com.google.gcloud.datastore.Entity;
import com.google.gcloud.datastore.Key;
import com.google.gcloud.datastore.KeyFactory;
```

Comment: Looks like a build system problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just download it from Maven Central, even if you do not want to use some proper build tool like Gradle or even Maven: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/cloud/google-cloud/0.8.0/google-cloud-0.8.0.jar

As you do not want to use a proper build tool with transitive dependency management (like Gradle, Ant+Ivy, Maven in best-to-worst order) you of course also have to add all transitive dependencies manually. Look into the POM file of the library at https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/cloud/google-cloud/0.8.0/google-cloud-0.8.0.pom and also download and add all dependencies and their dependencies and their dependencies.

The google-cloud-0.8.0.jar is just an empty placeholder, so you cannot use something by just importing that JAR of course.

`com.google.gcloud.AuthCredentials` for example is actually contained in `gcloud-java-core` and `com.google.gcloud.datastore.Datastore` in `gcloud-java-datastore`. If you are interested in which JAR contains an actual class file you can easily use the Maven Central search for this like http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfc%3Acom.google.gcloud.datastore.Datastore

Answer (score 0):

Get JAR file from maven central, for example for 0.8 version here is [download link](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/google/cloud/google-cloud/0.8.0/google-cloud-0.8.0.jar). And then add JAR to your Eclipse project as usual.